# Error on defining hibernate xml file

Tags: hibernate

Hi every one I am trying to make small project with hibernate
I am using mysql
this is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <!-- <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
                    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/TestDB</property> -->

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
        <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name="cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>
        <property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/hibernate-config/ehcache.xml</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Person.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/PhoneNumber.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Account.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/HolidayCalendar.hbm.xml"/>

        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Item.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping class="com.hamada.hibernate.dto.UserDetails"></mapping>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

and this UserDetails.java file

```
package com.hamada.hibernate.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

also this is my main class

```
package com.hamada.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.hamada.hibernate.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user=new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("Ahmed");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();   
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

when i run the program i got this error

```
Jun 08, 2016 2:17:06 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.0.Final}
Jun 08, 2016 2:17:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jun 08, 2016 2:17:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:723)
    at com.hamada.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Maybe you miss some related jar's in your classpath

Comment: And this is related to Spring how?

Comment: I think all my jars are exist

Answer (score 0):

JCacheRegionFactory is part of hibernate-jcache module which is not part of hibernate-core, you need to include it into your classpath/maven/gradle config

Answer (score 0):

In your hibernate.cfg.xml, i see you have included some cache related properties, viz.

```
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>
<property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/hibernate-config/ehcache.xml</property>
```

From your question, I understand that you want to test a simple Hibernate demo project and for that if you do not need any cache functions, you comment out the above mentioned block of code. That way you will not receive the error again, as in this block of code you have included the JCacheRegionFactory and that is not present in the jars that you have used. [Here I am assuming you have included the jars present only inside the required folder of the hibernate release zip that you may have downloaded.]

Just in case, you need to include the cache code, then as @Arthur has already mentioned, you need to include the relevant file. As a starter, I can suggest that in your hibernate release version folder, you go to the path project/hibernate-jcache. There is a file named hibernate-jcache.gradle. Probably, you can try including that in your project and see if the error stops coming or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys the problem is solved . The problem as i founded was that the application could not recognize the hibernate xml file then i just put it inside src folder directly and it is working after that